# Sorting an array into a 'histogram'

Tags: scala

I am a fairly new software Engineering student, so my knowledge is limited.
I have been given a task to sort an array, which in this case is a set of lottery numbers to give a graph like output in the console, I could do this using a whole bunch of match statements but feel there must be a better way.

this is the exact brief given:

---

Suppose that the following declaration defines the number of times that each of the national lottery balls (1 ..49) has been drawn over a given period.

```
  var lottery = Array(23,16,18,19,26,13,22,    /*  1 ..  7 */
                20,14,22,18,21,15,17,    /*  8 .. 14 */
                24,15,18,20,13,14,20,    /* 15 .. 21 */
                18,22,20,16,19,11,20,    /* 22 .. 28 */
                16,28,22,20,15,17,17,    /* 29 .. 35 */
                21,21,19,20,14,22,25,    /* 36 .. 42 */
                19,17,26,18,20,23,12);   /* 43 .. 49 */
```

write a program to print a histogram showing the information graphically using stars like so:

1 (23)  | **********************
2 (16)  | ************

and so on..

---

any hints/ advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated as it has stumped me thus far. I am not asking for an exact solution just some guidance on what methods i could use to accomplish them as it is likely I have not come across them.
Thank you and have a good day.

---

*Edit* - the first way I completed the task.

```scala
object lottery {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var lotteryIndex = 1

    var lottery = Array(23,16,18,19,26,13,22,    /*  1 ..  7 */
                    20,14,22,18,21,15,17,    /*  8 .. 14 */
                    24,15,18,20,13,14,20,    /* 15 .. 21 */
                    18,22,20,16,19,11,20,    /* 22 .. 28 */
                    16,28,22,20,15,17,17,    /* 29 .. 35 */
                    21,21,19,20,14,22,25,    /* 36 .. 42 */
                    19,17,26,18,20,23,12);   /* 43 .. 49 */

    scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(lottery)

    var i = 1

    while(i < lottery.length){
      if(lottery(i) != lottery(i-1)){
        print("\n" + lotteryIndex + " (" + lottery(i) + ")  |  " + "*")
        i += 1
        lotteryIndex += 1
      }else{
        print("*")
        i += 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This kind of question on this forum is always too broad. It's unclear whether you know any Scala at all or at least know the basics (*e.g.*, how a basic Scala program is structured). In that case, you need to start with a good text book or tutorial. There are a number of them online. Then you know you're doing some formatted output, so study Scala's facilities for that. Make some attempt and then you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hints: `for (number <- lottery) { ... }` or `lottery.foreach(number => ...)`,`"*" * number` (yes, `*` is a method, that you can call on string), `"s1" + "s2" = "s1s2"`, `println("string")`

Comment: Hope you know some basics `lottery.zipWithIndex.map(e => f"${e._2 + 1}%2s" + "("+e._1+") |"+"*" * e._1).foreach(println)`

Comment: I gave it a go after posting, avoiding looking at comments and managed to complete the task using a rather weird method, I will take comments on board and attempt it in another manner thank you. will put my method in the body of the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. Each value in the array is the frequency count of the index, so you need to be able to create a string of asterisks ('*') whose length is the same as the frequency count. This can be achieved any number of ways, but perhaps the simplest is to define a function as follows:

```scala
def ast(fc: Int) = "*" * fc
```

Where `fc` is the frequency count and the number of asterisks required. So, for example, if `fc` is 5, the result of this expression will be `"*****"`.

Next we need a function that creates a line of output, given a ball number (`bn`) and the corresponding frequency count (`fc`):

```scala
def line(bn: Int, fc: Int) = f"$bn%2d ($fc%2d) | ${ast(fc)}%s"
```

Let's explain what's happening here. The `f` prefix to the string tells *Scala* that it contains string formatting information and must be interpolated. (Refer to [this explanation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) for further information.)

Whenever a `$` is encountered, whatever follows is treated as an expression that needs to converted to a string in the output. If the expression isn't a simple one such as just a variable or value name (if it's a function call, for example), then the expression must be wrapped inside braces (e.g. `${...}`). If a `%` follows the expression, then it identifies the format of the expression in a manner similar to the [*C* language `std::printf` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

So: `$bn%2d` converts the integer value `bn` into a two-digit decimal string; `$fc%2d` converts the integer value `fc` into a two-digit decimal string; and `${ast(fc)}%s` calls the function `ast` passing `fc` as an argument, and then inserts the resulting string into the output. (The `%s` is redundant in this latter case.)

(Note: One of the comments on your original question specifies a format of `%2s`. While this correctly formats the output to two characters, it doesn't check that the argument type is integer, and is, therefore, not recommended.)

Now we need to iterate through the array to call this latter function for each member of the array...

Firstly, note that we need the index as well as the value (the ball number is the array index + 1, since arrays are 0-based). The first step is to convert `lottery` from an `Array[Int]` into an `Array[(Int, Int)]` via the `zipWithIndex` method. This takes each index-value pair in the `lottery` array, and combines them into a *tuple* (with the value first, then the index), placing the result in another array.

We can then `map` each tuple value in the result to a line of output as follows:

```scala
val lines = lottery.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (fc, idx) => line(idx + 1, fc)
}
```

The above is a way of breaking open the tuple using a *partial function*. If you don't mind using tuple access members, this can also be achieved more tersely (but also more obfuscatedly) using:

```scala
val lines = lottery.zipWithIndex.map(p => line(p._2 + 1, p._1))
```

where `p` is a tuple of array index and frequency count. Choose whichever method you prefer.

Finally, we can iterate on the result to print out each line of the result:

```scala
lines.foreach(println)
```

This latter is a shorthand for:

```scala
lines.foreach(l => println(l))
```

So, putting this all together, we end up with the following:

```scala
object Lottery
extends App {

  // Lottery data
  val lottery = Array(23,16,18,19,26,13,22,    /*  1 ..  7 */
                      20,14,22,18,21,15,17,    /*  8 .. 14 */
                      24,15,18,20,13,14,20,    /* 15 .. 21 */
                      18,22,20,16,19,11,20,    /* 22 .. 28 */
                      16,28,22,20,15,17,17,    /* 29 .. 35 */
                      21,21,19,20,14,22,25,    /* 36 .. 42 */
                      19,17,26,18,20,23,12)    /* 43 .. 49 */

  // Get a string of asterisks of the required length.
  def ast(fc: Int) = "*" * fc

  // Get a line of the histogram from a ball number and frequency count.
  def line(bn: Int, fc: Int) = f"$bn%2d ($fc%2d) | ${ast(fc)}%s"

  // Get each line of output for the histogram.
  val lines = lottery.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (fc, idx) => line(idx + 1, fc)
  }

  // Print each line of the histogram
  lines.foreach(println)
}
```

Note that we haven't sorted the histogram (the code as it stands matches the output specified in your brief). If you need to have balls listed in descending order of frequency count, simply sort the zipped array using the frequency count:

```scala
val lines = lottery.zipWithIndex.sortBy(-_._1).map {
  case (fc, idx) => line(idx + 1, fc)
}
```

`sortBy` takes a function used as the sort value. Here, we take the frequency count and make it negative to reverse the order of the sort (if you want it sorted in ascending order of frequency count, remove the `-` sign).

Note that we must sort the array *after* zipping with the index, otherwise we'll lose the ball number association.

Some further observations:

- In *Scala*, the use of `var` is heavily discouraged. Prefer `val` instead. (It's possible to write code that *never* uses `var` at all.)
- `object`s (other than `package object`s) should typically have a capital first letter by convention.
- Extending `scala.App` allows the object's constructor to become the `main` method of the program, and simplifies matters.

Unsorted output (which matches your brief):

```scala
1 (23) | ***********************
2 (16) | ****************
3 (18) | ******************
4 (19) | *******************
5 (26) | **************************
...
```

Sorted output:

```scala
30 (28) | ****************************
 5 (26) | **************************
45 (26) | **************************
42 (25) | *************************
15 (24) | ************************
...
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment about needing a frequency count of the frequency counts (if I understand you correctly), here's how you would do that:

To get the frequency of each value, there are (again) many ways to do this. In this particular case, I'm going to use a `foldLeft` operation.

You can think of `foldLeft` as an accumulation operation: the first argument identifies a *zero* value—the initial value of the *accumulator*—while the second is a function which is applied to each member of the container (the `Array`). This latter function itself takes two arguments: the current accumulator value, and the value of the current element, and it returns a new accumulator value.

In this case, I'm going to use `foldLeft` to build an associative array (a `SortedMap`, which keeps its keys sorted in ascending order) that links each frequency count to the number of times that it occurs. (In this `SortedMap`, the _key_s are the frequency counts, and the *value* associated with each key is the frequency of that frequency count.)

Here's what that looks like (I've broken it down into a number of steps to make it more comprehensible):

```scala
// Required import.
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

// Our initial, empty map, which reports a frequency of zero if a key is not present.
// Note that a `SortedMap` keeps its keys sorted.
val zero = SortedMap.empty[Int, Int].withDefaultValue(0)

// Iterate through the frequency counts (`fc`) in the `lottery` array. `fm` is the current
// status of our map.
val freq = lottery.foldLeft(zero) {(fm, fc) =>

  // Determine the new count for this frequency count.
  val newCount = fm(fc) + 1

  // Create an association from the frequency count to this new count.
  val assoc = fc -> newCount

  // Add this association to the map, resulting in a new map. Any existing association
  // will be replaced.
  fm + assoc
}
```

If you've followed that, here's a terser version:

```scala
val freq = lottery.foldLeft(SortedMap.empty[Int, Int].withDefaultValue(0)) {(fm, fc) =>
  fm + (fc -> (fm(fc) + 1))
}
```

Now all that remains is to create the histogram lines and print them:

```scala
val lines = freq.map {
  case (k, v) => line(k, v)
}

lines.foreach(println)
```

(Note: The definition of the arguments for the `line` method need tweaking in light of the changes, but the behavior is identical.)

Output:

```scala
11 ( 1) | *
12 ( 1) | *
13 ( 2) | **
14 ( 3) | ***
15 ( 3) | ***
16 ( 3) | ***
17 ( 4) | ****
18 ( 5) | *****
19 ( 4) | ****
20 ( 8) | ********
21 ( 3) | ***
22 ( 5) | *****
23 ( 2) | **
24 ( 1) | *
25 ( 1) | *
26 ( 2) | **
28 ( 1) | *
```

Comment: I really appreciate the amount of effort you put into this response, and you've helped me with my studies thank you, it's a small thing but a massive help.

Comment: Hi sorry, I have just gone and ran this code. I don't think I did a great job at explaining the brief the fc should be the amount of times in that sample that that number appears. for example the number 11 only appears once so it should just have the one asterix. I will play around and see what I can do.

Comment: @FrazerEastman Could you update your question to show the whole of the brief you were given? I'll update my answer accordingly...

Comment: @FrazerEastman I updated the answer on the assumption that your initial code is close to the required functionality. Does it now do what you're looking for?